# Execute code after all tests in a Minitest::Spec test case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest

I am using `Minitest::Spec` for some Rails tests. I have a test case where I need to perform before/after actions around its tests. I can do this around each test like this:

```
class MyTestCase < MiniTest::Spec

  before do
    set_up_whatever
  end

  after do
    clean_up_whatever
  end

  it "does this" do ... end
  it "does that" do ... end

end
```

However, I only really need those `before` and `after` to run around all the tests in `MyTestCase` rather than around each of them.

I know that I can perform setup at the class level before defining the tests and I know that I can use `MiniTest.after_run` to perform cleanup after all tests (including all other test cases) but I need to be able to clean up after this test case before any others are executed.

Is it possible to specify code that runs after all of the tests in a single test case class such as `MyTestCase` have been executed but before other test cases are executed ?

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Evans' Minitest extension [`minitest-hooks`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/minitest-hooks) is what you need.

```rb
gem 'minitest-hooks'
```

And then, from the README:

```rb
require 'minitest/hooks'

describe 'something' do
  include Minitest::Hooks

  after(:all) do
    DB[:table].delete # for example
  end

  # specs go here
end
```

The gem also includes other hooks:

```rb
before(:all)

around # each spec (with a block)

around(:all) # whole test class (with a block)
```

One of the reasons I love Minitest is this sort of modularity.